# Why can't I read a KeyPress more than once in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

```
$KeyOption = 'Y','N'
while ($KeyOption -notcontains $KeyPress.Character) {
 $KeyPress = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
}
```

The first time I run this, I'm able to read the character, but the next time that I run this, not so much...

- Yes, I am running it in a PowerShell window
- No, I'm not running it
  from PowerShell ISE.

I looked at the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.host.pshostrawuserinterface.readkey?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0) for this and there's a related function called $host.UI.RawUI.[FlushInputBuffer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.host.pshostrawuserinterface.flushinputbuffer?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0#System_Management_Automation_Host_PSHostRawUserInterface_FlushInputBuffer), but running it doesn't seem to change the fact that I can only make it work once...is there something else I need to be doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run your code again *in the same scope*, `$KeyPress` still has the value from the previous run, and if the previous run managed to exit the `while` loop based on a valid keypress, subsequent runs won't even enter the loop.

Therefore, switch to a `do { ... } while (...)` loop:

```
$KeyOption = 'Y','N'
do {
  $KeyPress = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
} while ($KeyOption -notcontains $KeyPress.Character)
```